# Error DPY-3011 when connecting to python-oracledb to Oracle DB 12.1

Tags: python, oracle, airflow

I tried to connect to Oracle 12.1 using  [python-oracledb](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/) from airflow environment but I got the following error

```
DPY-3011: server logon version is not supported
```

What is this error mean and how I can solve it?

**Update**: I connect to Oracle 19c and it works fine without issues, so I suspect that python-oracledb is not compatible with Oracle 12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is raised when you are in thin mode and the logon type supported by the server is not supported. Looking at it further, however, there is no reason for this error and I have removed it from the code -- which will be released as python-oracledb 1.1.

As noted by Hussein, if you [enable thick mode](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#enabling-python-oracledb-thick-mode) then you can connect to older databases, depending on the Oracle Client version you are using.

Comment: Can you specify what version of the database you are using?

Comment: Further investigation may show that the restriction can be removed!

Comment: Yes the version that I use  is Oracle 12.1.0.1

Comment: Great. Thanks! That confirms my theory. ;-) I've just pushed changes to the python-oracledb repo on GitHub that eliminate this restriction. If you are able to build yourself you can verify for me; otherwise, it will be released with the next version.

Answer (score 0):

The lib python-oracledb works fine with 12.1, but you need to install a supported version. [Here](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#supported-oracle-database-versions) are the supported oracle database versions for each lib version.